# REGEXP_LIKE to match a specific word in a comma separated string

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a field in the database that contains comma separated values, and I am trying to use REGEXP_LIKE to match for a specific word within the string.

Basically, I want to match for the word SE but don't know how to approach it.

The values of the database field can be:

```
"SE, SEM, NE" This should match
"SI, SE" This should match
"SI, NE" This should not match
```

I tried the following regex but does not work well.

```
'(^|,)(SE)(,|$)'
```

Comment: What is wrong with that pattern of yours? If you mean there may be whitespace between `,` and `SE` use `(^|,\s*)(SE)(,|$)`. Or even `(^|,)\s*SE\s*(,|$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it's not matching in the second scenario

Comment: Yes, there is a space between the comma and `SE`. You do not mention it in your question, that your input can contain whitespace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how do I take into account for that? Basically the SE can be in the beginning of the word, it can be after a comma aswell

Comment: `(^|,)\s*SE\s*(,|$)`?

Comment: @Ahamed You can't use `instr('SE') > 0` as you will get `SED` as a match

Comment: If my answer below worked for you please consider accepting the answer. Else, please let know what still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match `SE` in between commas or start/end of string when enclosed with 0 or more whitespace chars use

```
(^|,)\s*SE\s*(,|$)
     ^^^  ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ukZCaX/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%5E%7C%2C)%5Cs*SE%5Cs*(%2C%7C%24)):

[image]

Comment: @Site Glad to help.